# Excel VBA Cut or copy and paste on change of cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am making an inventory system.What i want is to copy closing stock to opening stock column when date will change and closing stock keep its formula just copy values to opening stock.

Date is in cell "AF1" with today date formula  =Today()
Closing Stock is in Column AB2:AB75 with formula(Opening Stock - Sale = Closing stock)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Target = Range("AF1") Then
    Range("AB2:AB75").Copy
    Range("AA2:AA75").PasteSpecial
 Else

 End If
 End Sub
```

when i change date it crash TYPE MISMATCH 13 and This become highlight yellow

> If Target = Range("AF1") Then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to change anything within a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro, you need to disable event handling so that the sub does not trigger another event and try to run on top of itself.

Additionally, **Target** can be one cell or a large number of cells. You cannot reliably compare it to a single cell. You **can** however, reliably compare its [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) to a single cell's [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Range("AF1").Address Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("AA2:AA75") = Range("AB2:AB75").Value
    Else
        'something else...?
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Using [Application.EnableEvents property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx) tp disable events should only be done with error control rthat always turns it back on in case something goes wrong.

Comment: its working good just add one more thing to clear the columns B2:z2 can i use `Range("B2:Z2").ClearContents`  before Else

Comment: That sounds appropriate. You are in a Private Sub on a worksheet code sheet so explicitly referencing the worksheet is unimportant unless you need to reference another worksheet.

Comment: Thanks it is working and also clearing the contents also

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Address = "$AF$1" Then
     ' Avoid copy then paste by assigning the value itself
     Target.Worksheet.Range("AA2:AA75").Value = Target.Worksheet.Range("AB2:AB75").Value

  End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: It works well on first click. Subsequent clicks after clearing destination cells     are not working . What is the correct way to utilize these change events.

Comment: It works like a charm on my end. I'm going to update my answer to show you how to do without copy paste...